# How do I create sequential yet unique objects in canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, clock

*My question might be a little sketchy since I'm new to programming.*

- I'm drawing a clock on canvas.
- I drew numbered dials using '*for*' statement.

Now, I want those dials to be unique objects, so that I can manipulate them.
Like, when it's near one o'clock, I could highlight the dial numbered 1.

Can I do this? How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: learn from here :http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/

Comment: @Amrendra Thanks for your advice. I've been reading some tutorials on the site, but I never thought of searching the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not put each dials in an array? Arrays are great tool for handling multiple objects.

Comment: I'm not sure until my googling and researching is done, but I guess your answer is what I've been looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I guess I found a [tutorial](http://billmill.org/static/canvastutorial/bricks.html) I can start upon, thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

The canvas is just a bitmap, it has no concept of objects after you draw them on it.

In other words, the canvas is just a bunch of pixels. After you have drawn the dial number, there is no way to change it other than to completely redraw (which is fine).

Comment: I would vote your answer down but I can't just yet as your response isn't an answer.  Just because canvas is a bitmap, this doesn't mean he couldn't abstract away the drawing of the canvas by creating helper functions to do the low-level stuff for him.  That way, he can simply invoke a function on some class.  If you think about it, the DOM is just several abstractions away from, essentially, a low-level drawing API.

Comment: Maybe I'm not using the term, 'object' properly. My bad. I think I get the concept of the canvas now. Thanks!Well, let me put my question this way: I don't want to _draw_ twelve monkeys, but I want to *create* twelve monkeys, and I want to name 'em differently. How can I do that?